# In C - Can I initialize an array (and set the size) from within a function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to pass a pointer to a funcion, and in that function create an array, and set the passed pointer to that array.

What I'm trying to do is create an array inside the function and then use that array outside the funcion.

```
void createArray(int *myPointer)
{
    int intArray[20];

    *myPointer = &intArray[0]; // This line gets error:
                               // assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        intArray[i] = i + 10;
    }
}

int main(void)

{
    int *intPointer;
    createArray(&intPointer);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        printf("%d : %d \n", i, intPointer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `intArray` will be deleted as soon as `createArray` returns, so `myPointer` will end up pointing to invalid memory. Also, `&intArray[0]` is a pointer to `int`, but in `*myPointer = &intArray[0];` you're assigning it to a memory location for data of type `int`, which is invalid.

Comment: The variable `intArray` is *local* inside the `createArray` function. Once the function returns, the life-time of the array ends, and any pointer to it will become immediately invalid. You probably should read about *dynamic allocation* (`malloc` and `free`) in your text-books.

Comment: As for the problem of "returning" the pointer (once you have a valid pointer to some memory whose life-time won't end too early) why not actually *return* the pointer? What you're trying to do is emulating pass-by-reference in C, but you're forgetting one thing: The type of `&intPointer` in the `main` function is a pointer to an `int *`, i.e. `int **`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant to use

```c
void createArray(int **myPointer)
```

That will resolve the two type errors.

But that will make `main`'s pointer point to a variable that no longer exists after `createArray` returns. That's bad. And that's why you have to use `malloc` instead of automatic storage.

```c
void createArray( int **myPointer ) {
    int *intArray = malloc( 20 * sizeof(int) );

    *myPointer = intArray;  // Same as `&intArray[0]`
    if ( !intArray )
       return;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        intArray[i] = i + 10;
}

int main(void) {
    int *intPointer;
    createArray(&intPointer);
    if ( intPointer ) {
       perror( NULL );
       exit( 1 );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf( "%d: %d\n", i, intPointer[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the compiler error is the `*myPointer` dereferencing, which gives you the content of type `int` that the pointer points at. The compiler is saying that you can't assign the pointer `&intArray[0]` to a plain `int`.

Besides being invalid C, it wouldn't change where the pointer points. To do that, you would have to do `myPointer = &intArray[0];`. However, in this case you can't do that either because the `myPointer` is just a local pointer variable inside the function - a local copy of the pointer you passed. You need a way to update the pointer in `main()`.

Furthermore, we can never return a pointer to local data (data with "automatic storage duration") because that data ceases to be valid as soon as we leave the function.

The normal solution is to create dynamically allocated memory instead, since such memory persists throughout the execution of the program (or until you explicitly free it). There are two different ways to write a function for that:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc

int* createArray (void)
{
    int* result = malloc(20 * sizeof(*result));
    if(result == NULL)
        return NULL; // some error handling will be required here

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        result[i] = i + 10;
    }
  
    return result;
}

...
int *intPointer = createArray();
...
free(intPointer);
```

Alternatively you could pass the pointer itself by value, so that by doing the `*myPointer = ...;` assignment, you refer to where a `int**` points at:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc

void createArray (int** myPointer)
{
    int* result;
    result = malloc(20 * sizeof(*result));
    if(result == NULL)
    { 
        /* some error handling will be required here */ 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        result[i] = i + 10;
    }
  
    *myPointer = result;
}

...
int *intPointer;
createArray(&intPointer);
...
free(intPointer);
```

Either of these are ok and which one you use is mostly a matter of design. It's easier syntax to have the pointer returned, but then normally the return of functions is reserved for some error code.